# correlated sub query to select ids of earliest entry

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am currently using this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    SomeId INT,
    UtcDateTime DATETIME2
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT 1, DATETIME2FROMPARTS(2015,1,1,1,1,1,0,0)
        UNION 
    SELECT 1, DATETIME2FROMPARTS(2015,1,1,2,1,1,0,0)
        UNION 
    SELECT 2, DATETIME2FROMPARTS(2015,1,1,3,1,1,0,0)
        UNION 
    SELECT 2, DATETIME2FROMPARTS(2015,1,12,4,1,1,0,0)
        UNION 
    SELECT 2, DATETIME2FROMPARTS(2015,1,12,5,1,1,0,0)
        UNION 
    SELECT 3, DATETIME2FROMPARTS(2015,1,12,5,1,1,0,0)

SELECT * FROM #Temp ORDER BY UtcDateTime ASC

SELECT 
    *
FROM #Temp AS O1
WHERE UtcDateTime =
(
    SELECT MIN(UtcDateTime) FROM #Temp AS O2 WHERE O1.SomeId = O2.SomeId 
)
AND SomeId =
(
    SELECT MAX(SomeId) FROM #Temp AS O2 WHERE O1.SomeId = O2.SomeId AND O1.UtcDateTime = O2.UtcDateTime
)
```

The intention is to select the first occurrence for each entry with a distinct SomeId based on UtcDateTime. In other words, I am after these rows:

```
SomeId  UtcDateTime
1   2015-01-01 01:01:01.0000000
2   2015-01-01 03:01:01.0000000
3   2015-01-12 05:01:01.0000000
```

Is the above correlated sub query approach correct?

Comment: Why not just SELECT SomeId, MIN(UtcDateTime) FROM #temp GROUP BY SomeId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use ROW_NUMBER order by [UtcDateTime] and partitioned by [SomeId] to get the first occurrence.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY SomeId ORDER BY [UtcDateTime]) RN 
            FROM    #Temp
        ) t
WHERE   Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Two self-joins (three times same table mentioned) - is too much in my opinion

1)

```
SELECT *
FROM #Temp AS O1
WHERE not exists
    ( select 1 from #Temp O2 
      where O2.SomeId = O1.SomeId and O2.UtcDateTime < O1.UtcDateTime)
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM #Temp AS O1
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 O2.UtcDateTime
  FROM #Temp as O2
  WHERE O2.SomeId = O1.SomeId
  ORDER BY O2.UtcDateTime ASC
) O2
WHERE O1.UtcDateTime = O2.UtcDateTime
```

2.1) subquery with group by, min and join (apply will most likely lead to plan with loop join, while group by first and join after - to hash join)

3) for your sample case

```
SELECT O1.id, MIN(O1.UtcDateTime)
FROM #Temp AS O1
GROUP BY O1.id
```

4) for small tables; note, row_number is not searching so you are "disabling" all indexes and requesting for additional memory to populate new column

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT O1.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY O1.SomeID ORDER BY O1.UtcDateTime) as row_no
  FROM #Temp as O1
) O2
WHERE O2.row_no = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours is not wrong but you could try this (for simpler method):

```
SELECT SomeId, MIN(UTCDateTime) AS UTCDateTime FROM #Temp GROUP BY SomeId
```

First occurrence will captured for each 'SomeId'

Answer (score 0):

Select the rows where there are no rows with the same ID and an earlier timestamp:

```
SELECT SomeId, UtcDateTime
FROM Temp AS T1
WHERE NOT EXIST (
    SELECT 1 FROM Temp AS T2
    WHERE T1.SomeId = T2.SomeId
    AND T2.UtcDateTime < T1.UtcDateTime)
```